# how to compile this cpp file that uses gmp with g++ cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin, gmp

I followed all the instructions for setting up gmp with cygwin,
./configure make make install and make check.

The libgmp.a is in the path C:/C++/gmp-6.1.2/.libs 
I'm using this command to compile with g++

```
g++ -L/C:/C++/gmp-6.1.2/.libs -I/C:/C++/gmp-6.1.2 C:/foo/foo.cpp -lgmp
```

I get an error message that says : could not find -lgmp

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not install the gmp from the cygwin distribution?